# How to know client side OS by PHP & Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

In PHP and Javascript by which function can we know what's end users operating system when an end user uses a site?

Answer (score 4):

With an up-to-date [browscap.ini](http://browsers.garykeith.com/), you can use the [get_browser()](https://www.php.net/function.get-browser) php function.

For Javascript-based detection, check out [this script](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html) from quirksmode.org

Answer (score 3):

In javascript:

navigator.platform gives you a general idea (win32 for example).
navigator.userAgent can be parsed with this regex: `/^[^\(]*\((.*)]\)/` to give you what's in the first set of parentheses. This typically is split up into more sub-sections, for example:

```
"Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.1.3pre"
```

[Zytrax](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/browser_ids.htm) maintains a wonderful list of useragents.

in PHP:

browser.php parses the user agent into the OS, Browser, and Browser version:

- http://apptools.com/phptools/browser/source.php

Keep in mind though that no matter how you detect it, it can be faked.